# Docker-compose run script after container starts

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

My goal is to have a one-liner (kinda) for building and starting my app. I want to be able to execute this command and run several additional commands related to my app (like migrations, init and starting a websocket server).
But when I try to use ENTRYPOINT directive my php service runs commands but the service itself is not working properly.

docker log nginx shows me this error:

`[error] 31#31: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,`

If I comment out ENTRYPOINT in back.dockerfile my app runs fine, but I have to manually run those artisan commands

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
```

Is there a way to achieve such result?

My docker-compose.yml

```
networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
    tty: true

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/back.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - node
    networks:
      - laravel

  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/front.dockerfile
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
```

back.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add bash
RUN alias composer='php /usr/bin/composer'
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
COPY ./app/composer.json ./app/composer.lock ./
COPY ./app .
RUN composer install --no-scripts --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/storage

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 6001
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
php artisan migrate --path 'database/migrations'
php artisan app:init
php artisan websockets:serve
exec "$@"
```

Comment: You're not running the `php-fpm` command that the official image does. https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/f2b879649fb8238dfa96592c49cd676601ee33a1/7.4/alpine3.15/fpm/Dockerfile

Comment: have you tried running `docker-compose up` without detachable mode to see if any error pops up in the console?

Comment: @HansKilian How can I run it? If I put CMD ["php-fpm"] on the bottom of dockerfile it changes nothing

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. That's why I put it as a comment and not as an answer. Without knowing what 'artisan' is, I would imagine that your last artisan command runs a server that doesn't exit. And that makes it hard to also run another server command.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, last command keeps server alive